How to calculate pitch and roll using linear acceleration of an IMU sensor?
I discovered the formula below for calculating pitch and roll using the linear acceleration data from an IMU sensor (ax, ay, az). First, I want to confirm whether the formula for pitch and roll are accurate. Second, which formula should I use for calculating pitch? Based on my data, both pitch formulas yield the same values but with opposite signs.
// Roll
Roll = atan2(ay,az);

// Pitch (formula 1) 
Pitch = atan2(-ax, sqrt(ay^2 + az^2));

// Pitch (formula 2) 
Pitch = asin(ax/sqrt(ax^2+ay^2 + az^2));

The image below shows the XYZ axis of the sensor. The forward move of the robot is opposite of XL.

I appreciate any help in advance.
